# Labelling plots using list of images

Tags: plotting, labeling

I have plotted the following:

```
p1 = Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 3 \[Pi]}, PlotStyle -> Red, 
   PlotLabels -> Placed["Cat1", Above]];
p2 = Plot[Cos[x], {x, 0, 6 \[Pi]}, PlotStyle -> Blue, 
   PlotLabels -> Placed["Cat2", Above]];
Show[p1, p2, PlotRange -> All]
```

which gives:

[image]

Now I wonder how one can change the labels into pictures of two cats? 
link to [cat1](https://www.stylist.co.uk/images/app/uploads/2017/10/24184627/d82c29b23a574d0de11df28351edde1e-256x256.jpg?w=256&h=256&fit=max&auto=format%2Ccompress) and [cat2](https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/625769159339737088/2dwpQAXA.jpg). Surly this might be funny but the point of my question is to know how to label plots using images?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
p1 = Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 3 \[Pi]}, PlotStyle -> Red, 
   PlotLabels -> Placed["Cat1", Above]];
p2 = Plot[Cos[x], {x, 0, 6 \[Pi]}, PlotStyle -> Blue, 
   PlotLabels -> Placed[Import["ExampleData/spikey.tiff"], Above]];
Show[p1, p2, PlotRange -> All]
```

which produces

[image]

Now replace the spikey with your cat images.

I'm prompted to wonder aloud that you didn't find this for yourself.